# Getting ";" expected error simple fix, new to java and Netbeans

Tags: java

not sure what is wrong keeps telling me i need a semicolon and parentheses

```
package savingsaccount;

/**
 *
 * @author cgw94
 */
public class SavingsAccount {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Savings    Account    Balances/Month    Saver1/n");
         double savingBal1=2000; double savingBal2=3000;
        for(int n=1; n<12; n=n+1){


            savingBal1=(savingBal1*.04)/12)+savingBal1;

            savingBal2=(savingBal2*.04)/12)+savingBal2;

            System.out.println(n"/n"savingBal1"/t/t/t/t/t"savingBal2"/n");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(n"/n"savingBal1"/t/t/t/t/t"savingBal2"/n");` is a mess. You should revisit that line.

Comment: java doesn't have string interpolation in that way xD

Comment: Escape sequences should use a backslash, e.g. `\t` for tab.

Comment: Remove one bracket from ur savingbal1 n 2,

Answer (score 1):

missing String concatenation operator `+` operator or other ways

```
System.out.println(n"/n"savingBal1"/t/t/t/t/t"savingBal2"/n");
                    |             |           |          |
                    |             |           |          |
```

Answer (score 1):

You have extra parentheses that should be removed, when you are calculating `savingBal1` and `savingBal2`.  E.g. change

```
//                            v
savingBal1=(savingBal1*.04)/12)+savingBal1;
```

to

```
savingBal1=(savingBal1*.04)/12 +savingBal1;
```

You need `+` operators to concatenate your values together in your call to `println`.  If you are going for tab characters and newlines, the backslash character `\` escapes, not the normal slash `/`.  The `println` method will add a newline for you; there is no need to explicitly concatenate another one.

```
System.out.println(n + "\n" + savingBal1 + "\t\t\t\t\t" + savingBal2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not concatenating your `String` result...for example...

```
System.out.println(n + "/n" + savingBal1 + "/t/t/t/t/t" + savingBal2 + "/n");
```

Also, `println` will end in a new line

Also...

```
savingBal1=(savingBal1*.04)/12)+savingBal1;
           1              0   1
```

Has an extra closing `)` without a corresponding `(`...